# Rewriting the URL to echo out in a $_GET variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm following a YouTube tutorial ([YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRgHBu3msA4)) and can't proceed any further without solving this problem. I've spent hours trying to fix it and have got no where.

What I'm trying to do is pass the URL as a query string to then be fed back into an App function to be echoed out even if it doesn't exist. I've written an `.htaccess` file to rewrite a URL so that it can do this but for whatever reason it's not working like the video shows.

In theory I should be able to type: `localhost/mvc/public/a/b/c/d` and have it echo out `a/b/c/d`

Here's my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /localhost/mvc/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And here's the function:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->parseUrl();
}

public function parseUrl(){
    if(isset($_GET['url'])){
        echo $_GET['url'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you instantiate the class these methods are in?

Comment: Yeah it's being instnatiated from an index.php file

Comment: So if you put `die("x")` in the construct or in the `parseUrl()` method you see an x on your page?

Comment: I already tried "Hello World" but yes...'x' shows when I do that

Comment: FYI: that tutorial has nothing to do with MVC. It might be partially related to the fact, that MVC as an architectural solution is mean for large-scope project and not 100-line hello world examples.

Comment: .........Yes it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew!!! Solved. The problem was my RewriteBase parameter...For the video the path was different and I edited it for my own directory, which I thought was correct...It works with `RewriteBase /mvc/public` my error was having "localhost" precede it. I guess this is already accounted for in the www folder.

FYI this dealt with a minimalist routing feature for the tutorial's application.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder that when you tried `localhost/mvc/public/a/b/c/d`, what happened, e.g., is there any other errors or warning displayed? Or an 404 error occurred?

Maybe it's due to apache's configuration? If possible, turn on the rewrite module on your server (if you uses Apache):

For Ubuntu:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

For other os: find your httpd.conf or any other apache's configuration file, and uncomment the 'LoadModule rewrite_module ...' line, then restart the apache server.

And I suggest you to enable PHP's display_errors, which is helpful for you to analyze where your error is.